# how to get and display the EXTRA_TEXT in an activity that is send by another activity with its Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I made a Login activity and on successful login, I sent the username with Intent as EXTRA_TEXT to start Home activity. But my app  is crashing when i tried to get the username and display it in TextView.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.home);
    TextView textView = new TextView(getApplication().getApplicationContext());
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String user = intent.getStringExtra(Login.EXTRA_TEXT);
    textView.setText(user);
    relativeLayout.addView(textView);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}
```

Comment: I've tried editing as per the answers got till now but still I cannot make username visible as TextView. Can anyone give some suggestions.

Comment: The problem is that I am not able to fetch the EXTRA_TEXT from the Intent. *Someone please correct the 5th and 6th lines of above code snippet.*

Answer (score 1):

```
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //View should be set first
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.home);
        TextView textView = new TextView(getApplication().getApplicationContext());
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String user = intent.getStringExtra(Login.EXTRA_TEXT);
        textView.setText(user);
///////////////modified/////////////////////////////
        relativeLayout.addView(textView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

Comment: I tried it. Still that TextView is not displaying in Home Activity.

Comment: You need to set LayoutParams to TextView.  Only then it will be visible.

Comment: I tried your edits. Still its not visible. *The problem is that I couldn't fetch that extra text sent with the intent to start home activity*. Please help me to fetch it correctly.

Comment: I could display the TextView when I tried `textView.setText("quoted string");` .I just cant fetch and display extra text(**username**) that was sent there.

Comment: Show us how are you calling this activing. that is, the intent creation part.

Comment: `String savedpassword = db.retrieve_password(username,db);
            if(password.equals(savedpassword))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, username);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
`

Comment: Got it right. It was my mistake in puting EXTRA_TEXT. Instead of `EXTRA_TEXT` I put it as `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`. That created the problem. Thanks for your efforts and directions in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

is when you link your layout to your class

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.home);
```

is when you try to reach RelativeLayout from your layout.

If you don't link your layout to your class, how can you reach your RelativeLayout?

Link your layout to your class first and after call your component, in this case, RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

before

```
findViewById(R.id.home)
```

Comment: I tried as u said. But it does't displayed that TextView. @joe-frostick